# Explicit generic function constraint causes type widening

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Here's a (semi) toy question that stemmed from trying to solve a [type-challenge](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00017-hard-currying-1/README.md)

Consider the following code:

```js
declare function echo<Fn>(fn: Fn): Fn
const e = echo((a: string, b: number) => true)
```

Here the return type of `e` is inferred to be `true`.

Now lets add a constraint to `Fn` to force it to be a function type:

```js
declare function echoFunc<Fn extends (...args: any) => any>(fn: Fn): Fn
const ef = echoFunc((a: string, b: number) => true)
```

Now the inferred return type of `ef` is widened to `boolean` (as opposed to `true` in the first case).

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtX3AAscAeAMVQD4AKRVALngoEpGKAoMPAZwwPgC8BMMWrUojXjCyoA5gBp4AI0apkAWyUgYzQZXgYYyEM3YB6M-CvwAegH527UJFgIU6bHmHEyaMOXwQAA8MEFRgbnhqADpY2FluRihUAE9dAX1klJo6NlRWJlROHj4QREFvHF90MQl4KRkFZVUNLR09AyMTc0tre3YgA)

Why the discrepancy?

***Note 1:***

*A function-type that has a literal return value probably isn't all that useful, but this issue did affect my ability to solve [the type-challenge](https://tsch.js.org/17/play) "correctly" because I aim to constrain my types as early as possible to reduce the amount of conditional typing and avoid the `never` type.*

*If the challenge used more realistic return-types, this would have slipped by.*

***Note 2:***

*The return type of `f` below:*

```js
const f = () => true
```

*is directly inferred to be `boolean` (which seems to tie in with [this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676))*

*Bearing this in mind, it seems that the lack of widening in the first example, `echo()`, is the inconsistency here.*

[*Playground Link*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAFASiQPhlATgVwFMAoAelJkpgD0B+IA)

Comment: Yeah I'm not seeing why this is happening, nor can I find issues about it.  One *could* try to step through the tsc with a debugger to find what's happening and then do a git blame on the relevant lines, but that's more effort than I think I'm going to put into this

Comment: Could you explain more about your situation? Because I can't think of a use case where a function that only ever returned true would be useful.

Comment: @JacobWeisenburger The use case is specifically to satisfy the tests laid out in [this type challenge](https://tsch.js.org/17/play). Like you say, a real-world application of this seems unlikely... hence me referring to it as a toy problem.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for taking a moment to look into it. Stepping through tsc does indeed sound like a step too far. I'll think more about real-world issues that might stem from this, but at the moment, it's in my "quirk" list only.